# Resource controller Concept In Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-7

As I am learning laravel I am unable to understand that when I am trying to access my edit.blade.php page by typing posts/edit in URL(that file is in resource/views/posts)
it is calling the method show and printing "show" on that page and if I type posts/posts/edit the edit.blade.php(mentioned below) is showing up. please guide me what I am doing wrong here

edit.blade.php

```
@extends('main')
@section('content')
<h1>Update Post</h1>
<form method="POST" action="{{route('posts.update', $post) }}"  >
    @method('PUT')
    @csrf
    <input type="text" name="title"><br><br>
    <input type="text" name="body"><br><br>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Update</button>
</form>
@endsection
```

PostController.php (a resource controller)

```
    <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use App\posts;
use Sessions; 


class PostController extends Controller
{ 
    public function create()
    {
        return view('posts.create');   
    }

    public function store(Request $request)
    {
       $post = new posts;
        $post->title = $request->input('title');
        $post->body = $request->input('body');
        $post->save();
        return redirect('posts/read');
    }

    public function show($data)
    {
       echo "show";
    }

    public function edit($id)
    {
        return view('posts.edit');
    }

    public function update(Request $req, $id)
    {
        echo posts::where('title' , $req->title)
        ->update(['body'=>$req->body]);
        return redirect('/');
    }

    public function destroy($id)
    {
        $post = posts::find($id);
        $post->delete();
        return redirect('/');

    }
}
```

route:

```
Route::resource('posts', 'PostController');
```

Comment: Which error you get? See the official resource controller doc here https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/controllers#resource-controllers

Comment: You don't use model-route-bindings, which would probably solve your issue. Instead of sending in the `$id` to your controllers (the argument to each method), simply do `posts $post`. Then you have your `$post` variable ready, and you do not need to fetch it manually.

Comment: Also, sidenote - your model violates Laravel naming conventions. It should be `Post` (first letter capitalized, singular) and not `posts` (all lowercase, plural).

Comment: If you are just starting with this model and that controller, you might be better off deleting both, then regenerating them with `php artisan make:model Post -rc` (generate the model `Post` with a resourceful controller already defined).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your routes are like so:

```
GET posts/{post}/edit    EDIT
GET posts/{post}         SHOW
```

So the URI `posts/edit` is matching the SHOW route:

```
posts/edit             posts/{post}
                       posts/edit
```

The URI `posts/posts/edit` is matching the EDIT route:

```
posts/posts/edit       posts/{post}/edit
                       posts/posts /edit
```

This is expected and how the routes are setup.

[Laravel 7.x Docs - Controllers - Resource Conrollers](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/controllers#resource-controllers)

Comment: But the method that I want to use is PUT (to update), how is it still calling show method if the methods are different. Please guide me

Comment: how is what showing? ... you literally are saying you are typing in the URL which would mean its a GET request

Answer (score 0):

First of all you change your controller like this

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use App\Post;
use Sessions; 


class PostController extends Controller
{ 
    public function create()
    {
        return view('posts.create');   
    }

    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $post = new Post;
        $post->title = $request->input('title');
        $post->body = $request->input('body');
        $post->save();
        return redirect('posts/read');
    }

    public function show($id)
    {
       $post = Post::find($id);
       return view(posts.show, ['post' => $post]);
    }

    public function edit($id)
    {
       $post = Post::find($id);
       return view(posts.edit, ['post' => $post]);
    }

    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        dd($request->all()); //check before update
    }

    public function destroy($id)
    {
        $post = Post::find($id);
        $post->delete();
        return redirect('/');

    }
}
```

Add `$post->id` to form `route` in your `edit.blade.php`

```
@extends('main')
@section('content')
<h1>Update Post</h1>
<form method="POST" action="{{route('posts.update', $post->id) }}"  >
    @method('PUT')
    @csrf
    <input type="text" name="title"><br><br>
    <input type="text" name="body"><br><br>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Update</button>
</form>
@endsection
```

Then you create `show.blade.php` in `view/posts` folder and put this code to `show.blade.php`

```
@extends('main')
@section('content')
<h1>Show Post</h1>
<h1>{{ $post->title }}</h1> 
<p>{{ $post->body }}</p> 
@endsection
```